# Pandas Datatype Conversion issue

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, type-conversion

I have a pandas series that looks like this: a bunch of `unicode` strings

```
>>> some_id
0    400742773466599424
1    400740479161352192
2    398829879107809281
3    398823962966097921
4    398799036070653952
Name: some_id, dtype: object
```

I can do the following but I lose the precision.

```
>>> some_id.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
0    4.007428e+17
1    4.007405e+17
2    3.988299e+17
3    3.988240e+17
4    3.987990e+17
Name: some_id, dtype: float64
```

But if I do `some_id.astype(int)`, I get the following: `ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10`

How can I convert them to `int` or `int64` type while preserving the precision ?
I am using Pandas `0.16.2`

UPDATE: I found the bug. `some_id.astype(int)` or any other form of it should work. Somewhere along the thousands of rows I have, some_id has a `string` of *text* (not a *string*ed number), so it was stopping the `int64` conversion.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you use `some_id.astype(np.int64)`?

Comment: What version of Pandas are you using.  Given your sample data above, I didn't have any problem converting some_id from an object to an int (Pandas 0.14.1).  Also, you don't loose precision converting to numeric, it just isn't displayed.

Comment: @Alexander might be time to upgrade - 0.16.2 is the current release :)

Comment: @Alexander: Actually, precision *is* lost if you convert to floating point.  Consider `int(float("100000000000000001"))`, which returns `100000000000000000`.

Comment: @Alexander: you *do* lose precision, because there are too many digits for a float to represent here.  Take the OP's series and look at `ser.astype(np.int64) - ser.astype(float).astype(np.int64)`.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser, I take your point that there are potential rounding issues due to floating point representation of the numbers (e.g. 1 becomes .9999..., and taking the int of that results in zero).  That wasn't the precision I thought the OP was referring to, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Alexander: you should see a series with 0,0,1,1,0 as values.  You can confirm this by trying `x = 398829879107809281; x - int(float(x))` at the console.

Comment: @DSM Confirmed.  My original numbers lost this very precision we are discussing when I converted, which subsequently gave no differences.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out... I have added the Pandas version I am using (for reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original series of numbers:

```
s = pd.Series([400742773466599424, 400740479161352192, 398829879107809281,
               398823962966097921, 398799036070653952], dtype=object)

>>> s
0    400742773466599424
1    400740479161352192
2    398829879107809281
3    398823962966097921
4    398799036070653952
dtype: object
```

Simply converting using `.astype(int)` should be sufficient.

```
>>> s.astype(int)
0    400742773466599424
1    400740479161352192
2    398829879107809281
3    398823962966097921
4    398799036070653952
dtype: int64
```

As an interesting side note (as pointed out by @Warren Weckesser and @DSM), you can lose precision due to floating point representation.  For example, int(1e23) gets represented as 99999999999999991611392L.  I'm not sure if this was the precision to which you referred, or if you were merely talking about the displayed precision.

With your sample data above, two numbers would be off by one:

```
>>> s.astype(np.int64) - s.astype(float).astype(np.int64)
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Dagrha is right, you should be able to use :

```
some_id.astype(np.int64)
```

the type will then be :

```
In[40]: some_id.dtypes
Out[41]: 
some_id    int64
dtype: object
```